# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: program (wrong name: program/Program)

Tags: java, compilation

I wrote a program on my mac and compiled it via terminal:

```
cd user/desktop/Code/Program/src/program
javac Program.java
**java Program**
```

Then I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Program (wrong name: program/Program)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:791)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:480)
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Source code:

```
package learning;

public class Learning{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] wordListOne = {"you are","I know","I eat"};
        String[] wordListTwo = {"a poo","a funny","a posh"};
        String[] wordListThree = {"Sandwich","person","object"};

        int oneLength = wordListOne.length;
        int twoLength = wordListTwo.length;
        int threeLength = wordListThree.length;

        int rand1 = (int) (Math.random() * oneLength);
        int rand2 = (int) (Math.random() * twoLength);
        int rand3 = (int) (Math.random() * threeLength);

        String phrase = wordListOne[rand1]+" "+wordListTwo[rand2]+" "+wordListThree[rand3];

        System.out.println(phrase);
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have a class called `Program`?

Answer (score 8):

Try using this.

```
javac learning/Learning.java
java learning.Learning
```

Your program is called `Learning`, not `Program`. You must do this from the directory in which the `learning` folder is. Example:

```
C:/path/to/files/learning/Learning.class
```

Then navigate to `C:/path/to/files/` using the `cd` command:

```
cd C:/path/to/files/
```

And then execute your statements.

Comment: I just called it learning for this tutorial and forgot about the source code, damnit

Comment: I do the above and it gives me the error i posted

Comment: @user1992091 The first line is different. What does it say? Also, did you put your `.java` files in a folder called `learning`?

Comment: yes. my folder goes as follows: Desktop/Code/Learning/src/learning/Learning.java and Learning.class

Comment: @Doorknob - `java learning/Learning` is WRONG.  It should be `java learning.Learning`

Answer (score 0):

Change the file name to Learning.java

then compile and run it( Learning.java not program.java)

the file name should be same as that of the static class.

Comment: [New Source Code](http://pastebin.com/index/dig0Yekb)

Comment: still having issue?
either you have to change the class name to Program or change the program.java to Learning.java

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError usually means that a class that was available at compile time isn't available at run time.  For example your compile and runtime classpaths don't match. Here is a blog post that explains it in more detail: http://javarevisited.blogspot.ca/2011/06/noclassdeffounderror-exception-in.html?m=1